# Проверять поля input на заполнение данных

Tags: javascript, html

Делаю приложение маршрута на яндекс картах с API яндекса.

Есть строка:

```
ymaps.route(
[routeFrom, routeIn, routeIn2, routeIn3, routeIn4, routeIn5, routeTo],
{mapStateAutoApply:true})
```

**routeFrom** , **routeIn**, **routeIn2** и тд это поля input, точнее их значения

> var routeFrom = document.getElementById('route-from').value

То есть, поле `routeFrom` - начальная точка, `routeTo` - конечный пункт.
а **routeIn**, **routeIn2**, **routeIn3**, **routeIn4**, **routeIn5** - это промежуточные пункты.

Получается что поля routeFrom и routeTo заполнять пользователю обязательно, а вот routeIn, routeIn2 и тд. - не обязательно.

Но получается что если пользователь не заполнил поле routeIn (либо заполнил не все (а всех их 5)) , в таком случае выдает ошибку, так как тут то они объявлены:

```
ymaps.route(
[routeFrom, routeIn, routeIn2, routeIn3, routeIn4, routeIn5, routeTo],
{mapStateAutoApply:true})
```

Можно ли каким-то образом проверять поля на заполненность и если они заполнены, то подставлять их в эту функцию?

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(routeFrom != '' && routeTo != '' && (routeIn != '' || routeIn2 != '' || routeIn3 != '' || routeIn4 != '' || routeIn5 != '')){
   ymaps.route([routeFrom, routeIn, routeIn2, routeIn3, routeIn4, routeIn5, routeTo],{mapStateAutoApply:true})
}else if(routeFrom != '' && routeTo != ''){
   ymaps.route([routeFrom, routeTo],{mapStateAutoApply:true})
}else{
   alert('Ошибочка! Неприятна :(')
};
```

Если правильно понял, то вот так

Comment: Не совсем то. Поле routeIn , routeIn2 и тд, (их всего 5). Но может быть так, что заполненно только 2, или 1, или 3, и тд, как пользователю вздумается

Comment: @Денис, исправил. Попробуй так